# getting error as sun.misc.Unsafe cannot be resolved while modifying library

Tags: java, android, guava

i'm developing an android sdk for my project and for that i'm using `google-http-java-client`
in sdk .
i want to make some changes in `google-http-java-client`  so that  i can use it in my app .
for instance i want to add some custom headers in `com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders` . For that i have extract the source code but im getting an error in `com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes`  as

> import sun.misc.Unsafe cannot be resolved.

So is there any other way to modify this library ???

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The `UnsafeComparator` uses `Unsafe` which is not on the default classpath<sup>1</sup> in android, but there's also the `PureJavaComparator` provided as a fallback. Removing the whole part dealing with `Unsafe` should suffice, as in `getBestComparator()` it gets looked up via its name and in case of an exception the fallback gets used.

---

<sup>1</sup> I was thinking it doesn't exist in android, but I believe Kevin saying it does. Anyway, saying that it's not on the default classpath is surely correct (regardless of its existence).

Comment: Are you quite sure that sun.misc.Unsafe doesn't exist in Android? I would be extremely surprised. More likely, it just isn't in the default compilation classpath.

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion: I'm not sure at all, it was just an assumption based on what I've heard. But based on my experience, removing the reference might be much faster than finding what to include in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on things shippped with the Oracle/Sun JDK that aren't provided by Google. Short answer: don't do that. Long answer: see ['Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages'](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).

Comment: @curious_mind: Sure you can, using it in compiled form is no problem at all and if you really need to use the sources, you just need to leave out the offending part. You could leave out the whole class `UnsignedBytes` unless you need it.

Comment: @EJP: You're wrong, nobody is relying on Unsafe. It's not him as it appears in the Guava library and they're not relying on it as they provide a fallback solution.

Comment: @maaartinus That can only mean that somebody else is relying on it. Same remarks apply. Nothing wrong about it whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP Are you quite sure that sun.misc.Unsafe doesn't exist in Android? I would be extremely surprised. More likely, it just isn't in the default compilation classpath.